# JQuery: Dialog's current position after moving

Tags: jquery, dialog

I got this little problem. I cant get the current position of JQuery after I move it.
Seems like it wont update its position. It just gives the first one.

Another problem I came up with was that the dragStop event wont work either..

Comment: Well I tried this in the close event.

$(this).dialog("option", "position");

I also tried

$(this).dialog().position();

I have this ajax call that would save the current position into a file.

Comment: well, that works here, http://jsfiddle.net/nBrTP/

Comment: thanks! So it's possible. I have to figure out what is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#idOfYourDialog').dialog('widget').position();
```

use the 'widget' flag to get the ui-dialog (the div that is your dialog) to get it' parameters.

As for the dialog drag-stop - are you binding in the init or through bind? Can you post a code sample?

Comment: I bind it in the init yes.. I tried to alert something out after the event was fired but wihtout success..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jBHHd/1/ - might help, i can't change my answer further to help you (SO keeps erring)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I have this ajax function that calls content from the server. That might be the problem.

I have it like:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: href,  
                success: function(data) {

                    if(handleAjaxErrors(data)==false) {

                        openWindowsCount++;

                        $(data).dialog({
```

Comment: you may edit your post above and add this codes... that's how SO works... ;)

Comment: by the way is it totally wrong way to implement that. I mean the data contains a div which contains other html content..